# Flask-login User.get(userid) missing

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

Implementing flask-login there is a function that is called whenever a page is loaded or changed

`user_loader()`

in the flask docs example implementation they have this callback function defined as

```
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.get(user_id)
```

However user does not have the get function and I have been unable to find an implementation of it.

I am using the libraries:

```
ppretty
flask_login LoginManager
flask__babel
```

Where should I find the get function for the users

Comment: what is User? what do you want to get? , link to the docs where you find this, what you mean by where should i find get function. please give some more details so that we can solve your problem.

Comment: https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#how-it-works

Comment: this is the only docs i can find on the particular function i want to use